# Advanced pivot of table in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I've just recently started using Kusto and so far so good. 
However, I've run into a roadblock which I'm having some issues in solving.

I have the following table

```
datatable(name:string, gender:string, occupation: string)
[
    "John", "Male", "Janitor",
    "Sam", "Male", "Pilot",
    "Mary", "Female", "CEO"
]
```

And I want to pivot it so I end up with a table like this

```
datatable(info:string, John:string, Sam: string, Mary: string)
[
    "Name", "John", "Sam", "Mary",
    "Gender", "Male", "Male", "Female",
    "Occupation", "Janitor", "Pilot", "CEO"
]
| where info != "Name"
```

The names in this case will always be unique, so that's not an issue.

Here is one of my pathetic attempts :)

```
datatable(name:string, gender:string, occupation: string)
[
    "John", "Male", "Janitor",
    "Sam", "Male", "Pilot",
    "Mary", "Female", "CEO"
]
| summarize d = make_bag(
    pack(
        name, pack_array(gender, occupation))
) by name
| evaluate  bag_unpack(d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution handles any number of columns:

```
let my_data = datatable(name:string, gender:string, occupation: string)
[
    "John", "Male", "Janitor",
    "Sam", "Male", "Pilot",
    "Mary", "Female", "CEO"
];
my_data
| getschema 
| project variable = ColumnName, type = ColumnType, i = ColumnOrdinal, Dummy = 1
| where variable != 'name'
| join kind = inner (my_data | project array = pack_array(*), Dummy = 1) on Dummy
| project name = tostring(array[0]), variable = variable, type, value = array[i]
| evaluate pivot(name, any(value))
```

All value columns are cast to 'dynamic' data type. To nevertheless retain the data type metadata, a 'type' column is added that holds the data type for any *row* in the output table.

Answer (score 1):

here's one option:

```
datatable(name:string, gender:string, occupation: string)
[
    "John", "Male", "Janitor",
    "Sam", "Male", "Pilot",
    "Mary", "Female", "CEO"
]
| as T
| summarize b = make_bag(pack(name, gender)) by info = "Gender"
| union (
    T
    | summarize b = make_bag(pack(name, occupation)) by info = "Occupation"
)
| evaluate bag_unpack(b)
```

Comment: Nice!

So, in my real world example, I have around 15 extra columns, I guess I'd have to do 15 different unions to make this happen?

Comment: Ideally, your data would be formatted in the way your queries require beforehand, I.e before you ingest it into Kusto. Manipulating the schema at query runtime as shown above could be OK for smaller datasets, but as your data grows will add non trivial overhead you could avoid.

Comment: Fair enough - However this is quite hard here as the output from this query is going to be "Information about John" for example (Shown in Grafana). The query would already be filtered down to maximum of 5 rows (names here).   -   In any case, I can't really create a column for every new name that arrives either to solve this :)

Comment: you can re-shape the data at ingestion time (one time setup) using an `update policy`, and if your source data is formatted as JSON - a JSON `ingestion mapping` (search Google / the Kusto docs for those terms). it is advised to do so once, at ingestion time, and not have to do it for each query you run, assuming most/all of your queries can't use the data as-is, and have to re-shape it

Comment: And is it acceptable to keep adding columns as new "names" come in?

Comment: if you're using a JSON `ingestion mapping`, as long as the mapping is being updated with new properties, then the table will be automatically extended when those properties are ingested. using an `update policy` would require you to update both the query/function being used in it, as well as the schema of the target table. you may find it easier to design the source data "better" (WRT how you plan to consume it in your queries) _before_ ingestion_ into Kusto

Comment: True indeed. I don't immediately see a better structure to try, but I can give it a thought. The main issue is that I also have a "timestamp" column to filter on. In the above example, that would be equivalent to "Give me information about John at time X" then pivot said information.